# SQL Server - Query The Data From XML File

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am new to XML stuff. I've figured out how to query and return the values from the XML file (example below).  However, I run into a problem that it only capture the first node of 'SerialNo' tag because the tag has the same node name "SerialNo" repeated. In the XML file, it has 4 serial numbers for SKU#TT234343, but it only gives me the first Serial11111. I am totally stuck and don't know how to list all of those serial#.

I would like the query result for SKU#TT234343, listing all 4 serial numbers if possible.

Please help.  Thanks!

The XML File looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<ROOT>
  <ShipNotice version="1" >
    <InvoiceDate>01/01/2015</InvoiceDate>
    <InvoiceNumber>6868686</InvoiceNumber>
    <ShipDate>02/02/2015</ShipDate>
    <ShipTime>2306</ShipTime>
    <PONumber>P444444</PONumber>
    <PODate>03/03/2015</PODate>
    <ShipCode>XXX</ShipCode>
    <ShipDescription>FedEx Economy</ShipDescription>
    <ShipTo>
      <AddressName>ShipABC</AddressName>
      <AddressContact>Name1</AddressContact>
      <AddressLine1>2222 Street Name</AddressLine1>
      <AddressLine2> </AddressLine2>
      <City>AUSTIN</City>
      <State>TX</State>
      <ZipCode>78111</ZipCode>
    </ShipTo>
    <BillTo>
      <AddressName>BillABC</AddressName>
      <AddressContact>Name1</AddressContact>
      <AddressLine1>1234 Street Name</AddressLine1>
      <AddressLine2>-SUITE 111</AddressLine2>
      <City>Los Angeles</City>
      <State>CA</State>
      <ZipCode>95136</ZipCode>
    </BillTo>
    <TotalWeight>324</TotalWeight>
    <EmptyCartonWGT>0</EmptyCartonWGT>
    <NumberOfCarton>1</NumberOfCarton>
    <DirectShipFlag>D</DirectShipFlag>
    <ShipFromWarehouse>88</ShipFromWarehouse>
    <ShipFromZip>94538</ShipFromZip>
    <ShipTrackNo>33333333</ShipTrackNo>
    <EndUserPONumber>55555555</EndUserPONumber>
    <CustomerSONumber/>
    <Package sequence="1" >
      <TrackNumber>666666666</TrackNumber>
      <PackageWeight>324</PackageWeight>
      <Item sequence="1" >
        <SOLineNo>1</SOLineNo>
        <MfgPN>XYZ1111111</MfgPN>
        <SKU>TT234343</SKU>
        <ShipQuantity>4</ShipQuantity>
        <CustPOLineNo>1</CustPOLineNo>
        <CustSOLineNo/>
        <Description>Server1234</Description>
        <CustPN/>
        <UPC/>
        <UnitPrice>1000</UnitPrice>
        <EndUserPOLineNo>0</EndUserPOLineNo>
        <SerialNo>Serial11111</SerialNo>
        <SerialNo>Serial22222</SerialNo>
        <SerialNo>Serial33333</SerialNo>
        <SerialNo>Serial44444</SerialNo>
      </Item>
      <Item sequence="2" >
        <SOLineNo>2</SOLineNo>
        <MfgPN>XYZ222222</MfgPN>
        <SKU>TT8848788</SKU>
        <ShipQuantity>4</ShipQuantity>
        <CustPOLineNo>2</CustPOLineNo>
        <CustSOLineNo/>
        <Description>GGG localization</Description>
        <CustPN/>
        <UPC/>
        <UnitPrice>0.00</UnitPrice>
        <EndUserPOLineNo>0</EndUserPOLineNo>
        <SerialNo/>
      </Item>
    </Package>
  </ShipNotice>
</ROOT>
```

The SQL Query:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @xmlData

SELECT 
InvoiceNumber, PONumber, PODate
, AddressName
, MfgPN, SerialNo
--, AddressContact, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, ZipCode
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/ROOT/ShipNotice/Package/Item')
WITH 
(
    --- #################  Level 1 #################
    InvoiceNumber [varchar](50) '../../InvoiceNumber',
    PONumber [varchar](100) '../../PONumber',
    PODate [varchar](100) '../../PODate',

    --- #################  Level 2 #################
    AddressName [varchar](100) '../../ShipTo/AddressName',


    --- #################  Level 3 #################
    MfgPN [varchar](100) 'MfgPN',
    SerialNo [varchar](100) 'SerialNo'

)
```

Comment: Anyone who is expert about XML?  Any different methods with the same result?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the newer technology XQuery instead of `OPENXML()`. Using XQuery, you can use [`nodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) method to shred the XML on elements that will correspond to the rows in the output, and use [`value()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to extract the element value :

```
SELECT
    shipnotice.value('InvoiceNumber[1]','varchar(20)') InvoiceNumber
    , shipnotice.value('PONumber[1]','varchar(20)') PONumber
    , shipnotice.value('PODate[1]','varchar(20)') PODate
    , shipnotice.value('(ShipTo/AddressName)[1]','varchar(100)') AddressName
    , item.value('MfgPN[1]','varchar(100)') MfgPN
    , serialno.value('.','varchar(100)') SerialNo
FROM @XML.nodes('/ROOT/ShipNotice') as t(shipnotice)
    OUTER APPLY shipnotice.nodes('Package/Item') as t2(item)
    OUTER APPLY item.nodes('SerialNo') as t3(serialno)
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/1855)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
| InvoiceNumber | PONumber |     PODate | AddressName |      MfgPN |    SerialNo |
|---------------|----------|------------|-------------|------------|-------------|
|       6868686 |  P444444 | 03/03/2015 |     ShipABC | XYZ1111111 | Serial11111 |
|       6868686 |  P444444 | 03/03/2015 |     ShipABC | XYZ1111111 | Serial22222 |
|       6868686 |  P444444 | 03/03/2015 |     ShipABC | XYZ1111111 | Serial33333 |
|       6868686 |  P444444 | 03/03/2015 |     ShipABC | XYZ1111111 | Serial44444 |
|       6868686 |  P444444 | 03/03/2015 |     ShipABC |  XYZ222222 |             |
```